# History Go back in links using javascript

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I'm having trouble getting this simple script to work in more browsers than Chrome.

```
<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
</script>
```

...

```
<a href="javascript:goBack()">Go back to previous page.</a>
```

I suspect this might be an old solution, but can't find one that works.

Any help here guys?

Thanks,
T

EDIT:

I've also tried this solution

```
<script>
function goBack() {
    window.history.go(-1);
}
</script>
```

Still, it only works in Chrome.

Comment: **window.history.back();** should work on all browser. You may use **onclick** instead of **href** to call the function. Please take a look: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp Also note that it only work if the previous page does exist in the history list.

Comment: Cheers dude. onclick solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try just

```
history.back()
```

or

```
history.go(-1)
```

you can even check if you have a back page where to go with

```
history.length
```

depending on the brower may be 0 (FF, Chrome) or 1 (IE) if is emtpy

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However it still only works with Chrome :/

Comment: history.go(-1) works fine on FF to me:

<html>
<script>
function goback(){
 history.go(-1);
}
</script>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="goback(); return false;">go back</a>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly.

> window.history.back(); should work on all browser. You may use onclick
>   instead of href to call the function. Please take a look:
>   w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp Also note that it only work if
>   the previous page does exist in the history list. –  highqweb 31 mins
>   ago